# How to build / compile firebase cloud functions with webpack

Tags: typescript, firebase, webpack, google-cloud-functions

I am using webpack to build my cloud functions (several reasons to this as path aliases, typescript and some other configs)

I have my `index.ts` file as well as `src` folder containing individual files for each function.

My `index.ts` file then exports them like this

```
import admin from 'firebase-admin';

admin.initializeApp();

export const func1 = require('./src/func1').default;
export const func2 = require('./src/func2').default;
```

The issue with webpack compared to something like `tsc` is that it requires all the code from required files and bundles it in index file, which for cloud functions is not ideal due to cold start performance.

What would be correct way to split these files into separate ones and ensure good cold start performance (i.e. only code for function that is being called is required).

My webpack config for firebase looks like this

```js
const config = {
  entry: {
    index: path.resolve(__dirname, './index.ts')
  },
  output: {
    filename: '[name].js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
    libraryTarget: 'commonjs'
  },
  mode: 'production',
  optimization: {
    nodeEnv: 'production',
    splitChunks: {
      chunks: 'all'
    },
    minimize: true,
    minimizer: [
      new ESBuildMinifyPlugin({
        target: 'es2020',
        minifyWhitespace: true,
        minifyIdentifiers: true,
        minifySyntax: true
      })
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      $tools: path.resolve(__dirname, '../../tools'),
      $types: path.resolve(__dirname, '../../types')
    },
    extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.js', '.mjs', '.json']
  },
  externals: ['firebase-functions', 'firebase-admin'],
  target: 'node',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(m?js|ts)$/u,
        exclude: /(node_modules)$/u,
        use: {
          loader: 'esbuild-loader',
          options: {
            loader: 'ts',
            target: 'es2020',
            tsconfigRaw: require('./tsconfig.json')
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [new CleanWebpackPlugin(), new ESBuildPlugin()]
};
```

Comment: What's your webpack config?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere added it to the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is solution I was able to cook up.

First, make each function its own entry in webpack, you can do so manually or via something like this

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

// Get all functions and store their names in an array, based on filename, use .js instead of .ts if thats your case
const functions = fs.readdirSync('./src').map(file => file.split('.ts')[0]);

// Add all functions to entries object
const entries = {};
functions.forEach(file => {
  entries[file] = path.resolve(__dirname, `src/${file}.ts`);
});

// Finally add your index file to entries object (if it is not already in src folder together with functions)
entries.index = path.resolve(__dirname, './index.ts');

// Use this in your webpack congig
const config = {
 entry: entries,
 // ...
}
```

This will result in something like this

```
dist/
  func1.js
  func2.js
  index.js
```

Then in your index file use [**non_webpack_require**](https://webpack.js.org/api/module-variables/#__non_webpack_require__-webpack-specific), this way webpack keeps them as `require()` in compiled code. Export all your functions, remember that each file will be at the root of the compiled folder.

```
import admin from 'firebase-admin';

admin.initializeApp();

export const func1 = __non_webpack_require__('./func1');
export const func2 = __non_webpack_require__('./func2');
```

Answer (score 0):

The principle of webpack is to tranform and optimise the JS, to minimize it and to pack it into a single file (for browser download optimization for example, not the topic here).

In your case, you have only 1 entry point. Webpack will follow all the dependencies and pack them into the same file.

The solution here is to have 2 separate/independant entry points, and like this you will have 2 output files. But sometime it's boring to do this because you want to mutualize some part of the code/initialization. It's always a matter of tradeoff

Comment: Splitting into different entries works for me, since I have some functions that rely on substantial amount of json data bundled with them, while others don't. I tried creating separate entry for each individual function, however my index.ts file still includes all of them due to that require so essentially setting multiple entries just creates more files at the moment.

Comment: Yes, you mustn't have a file which reference the function (your index) because it will aggregate the data. Why do you need this index.js? For local testing?

Comment: This is how firebase cloud functions expect users to export them. There needs to be an index file that export / requires your other functions.  When built with tsc, requires remain there. I am now thinking that I might need to ignore this index file, and just keep it as js one

Comment: My bad, I forget your Firebase Functions context... Yes, it's a constraint of firebase. You can try to use directly Google Cloud Functions instead of Firebase, but it will create an heterogeneous development environment.